# What are the differences between ESLint extends with and without require.resolve in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to configure ESLint for my project but I'm confused with the two ways extends are **with** `require.resolve` and **without** `require.resolve`:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended"
  ],
  ...
}
```

and with

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    require.resolve('@vercel/style-guide/eslint/browser'),
    require.resolve('@vercel/style-guide/eslint/react'),
    require.resolve('@vercel/style-guide/eslint/next'),
  ],
};
```

Is there the differences between these two ways of extending? What is the purpose of `require.resolve`. Does it neccessary?